# Populate an array with values from checkboxes and then submit all at once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm probably going to need some sort of jquery or JS to accomplish this, and since I suck at using either solution; I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction. Basically I want to be able to select a bunch of records and add them into an array.  Once I'm happy with my results, I hit the "Submit" button and off it goes. Think of it as an address book, select a bunch of names to export and then hit "Export" to export the names.

Jquery or JS comes into play because I want a div that shows the records that I've selected. So far I've gotten it to work by checking off what i want to export, but it would be nice to show what I've selected thus far in a separate box.

Comment: Check out jQuery selectors http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ You can do something like $("input:checked") to get an array of the selected records and dump them into a separate div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is similar example I found that does something like that using jquery:

http://jsfiddle.net/amirshim/sDDps/3/